# How to select only one item from a flatlist in React and change it's style?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm stuck with trying to make a flatlist work with one selection and change only it's background. I already got the id from the pressed item and I'm passing the information to another page. But after clicking, it's style is not changing. I need to select just one and if I click on another it should deselect the first one and keep the new one selected.

My code is as folows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Linking, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class Merchants extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            loading: false,
            merchantObj: [],
            btnDisabled: true,
            itemId: null,
            imgLink: null,
            listClicked: false,
        }
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const merchantUrl = 'http://165.227.43.115:8080/merchant/merchant'
        fetch(merchantUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ merchantObj: data, loading: false },
                    function () {
                        this.arrayholder = data;
                    })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }

    search = text => {
        console.log(text);
    };
    clear = () => {
        this.search.clear();
    };
    SearchFilterFunction(text) {
        //passing the inserted text in textinput
        const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function (item) {
            //applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
            const itemData = item.name ? item.name.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
            const textData = text.toUpperCase();
            return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });
        this.setState({
            //setting the filtered newData on datasource
            //After setting the data it will automatically re-render the view
            merchantObj: newData,
            search: text,
        });
    }
    FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 1,
                    width: "95%",
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: "#DCDCDC",
                }}
            />
        );
    }
    MerchSelected = (selectedId) => {
        if (this.state.btnDisabled === true) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.btnDsb}>
                    <Text style={styles.txtBtn}>Select</Text>
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', { itemId: this.state.itemId, itemImg: this.state.imgLink })}>
                    <View style={styles.btnSelect}>
                        <Text style={styles.txtBtn}>Select</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }
    }

    PressedItem = (itemId, itemImg) => {
        console.log(itemId)
        this.setState({ itemId: itemId, btnDisabled: false, imgLink: itemImg })
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.PressedItem(item.id, item.image)} >
                <View style={styles.listItem} >
                    <Image
                        style={{ width: 80, height: 80 }}
                        source={{ uri: `${item.image}` }} />
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 2 }}>
                        < Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }} > {item.name} </Text>
                        {item.shoppingOption == 'STORE' ? <Text>Store</Text> : <Text>In-Store  &amp; Online</Text>}
                        <Text>${item.minAmount} - ${item.maxAmount}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#00CED1' }}
                            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(`${item.website}`)}>
                            view website
                    </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Loading...</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <View style={styles.searchBar}>
                    <Searchbar
                        round
                        placeholder="Search"
                        onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
                        onClear={text => this.SearchFilterFunction('')}
                        value={this.state.search}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.merchantsList}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.merchantObj}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                        extraData={this.state}
                    >
                    </FlatList>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footerBtn}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', { itemId: undefined })}>
                        <View style={styles.btnSelect}>
                            <Text style={styles.txtBtn}>Cancel</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {this.state.btnDisabled === true ? this.MerchSelected('Sim') : this.MerchSelected('Nao')}
                </View>
            </View >
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f4',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    searchBar: {
        flex: 1,
        top: '5%',
        width: '90%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(242, 242, 244,0.5)'
    },
    merchantsList: {
        flex: 6,
        width: '95%',
    },
    footerBtn: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
    },
    listItem: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    notSelected: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f4'
    },
    listItemSlc: {
        backgroundColor: '#48D1CC',
    },
    btnSelect: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '95%',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: '#00CED1',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 2,
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginLeft: 8,
    },
    btnDsb: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '95%',
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginLeft: 8,
    },
    txtBtn: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#00CED1',
        fontSize: 20,
    },
})
```

Comment: Is `itemId` the id of the item pressed/clicked on that you want to change the background of? Can you be more explicit to what your expected result should be? i.e. what background should change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Linking, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class Merchants  extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            loading: false,
            merchantObj: [],
            btnDisabled: true,
            itemId: null,
            imgLink: null,
            listClicked: false,
            itemindex:"",
        }
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const merchantUrl = 'http://165.227.43.115:8080/merchant/merchant'
        fetch(merchantUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                //var l_Data = [];
                //for (var l_index = 0; l_index < data.length; l_index++)
                //{
                //    l_Data[l_index] = {

                //    }

                //}

                this.setState({ merchantObj: data, loading: false },
                    function () {
                        this.arrayholder = data;
                    })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }

    search = text => {
        console.log(text);
    };
    clear = () => {
        this.search.clear();
    };
    SearchFilterFunction(text) {
        //passing the inserted text in textinput
        const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function (item) {
            //applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
            const itemData = item.name ? item.name.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
            const textData = text.toUpperCase();
            return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });
        this.setState({
            //setting the filtered newData on datasource
            //After setting the data it will automatically re-render the view
            merchantObj: newData,
            search: text,
        });
    }
    FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 1,
                    width: "95%",
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: "#DCDCDC",
                }}
            />
        );
    }
    MerchSelected = (selectedId) => {
        if (this.state.btnDisabled === true) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.btnDsb}>
                    <Text style={styles.txtBtn}>Select</Text>
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', { itemId: this.state.itemId, itemImg: this.state.imgLink })}>
                    <View style={styles.btnSelect}>
                        <Text style={styles.txtBtn}>Select</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }
    }

    PressedItem = (itemId, itemImg) => {
        console.log(itemId)
        this.setState({ itemId: itemId, btnDisabled: false, imgLink: itemImg })
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.PressedItem(item.id, item.image), this.setState({ itemindex: item.id }) }} >
                <View style={this.state.itemindex == item.id ? styles.SelectedlistItem : styles.listItem} >
                    <Image
                        style={{ width: 80, height: 80 }}
                        source={{ uri: `${item.image}` }} />
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginLeft: 2 }}>
                        < Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }} > {item.name} </Text>
                        {item.shoppingOption == 'STORE' ? <Text>Store</Text> : <Text>In-Store  &amp; Online</Text>}
                        <Text>${item.minAmount} - ${item.maxAmount}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#00CED1' }}
                            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(`${item.website}`)}>
                            view website
                    </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>Loading...</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container} >
                <View style={styles.searchBar}>
                    <Searchbar
                        round
                        placeholder="Search"
                        onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
                        onClear={text => this.SearchFilterFunction('')}
                        value={this.state.search}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.merchantsList}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.merchantObj}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem}
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                        extraData={this.state}

                    />

                </View>
                <View style={styles.footerBtn}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', { itemId: undefined })}>
                        <View style={styles.btnSelect}>
                            <Text style={styles.txtBtn}>Cancel</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {this.state.btnDisabled === true ? this.MerchSelected('Sim') : this.MerchSelected('Nao')}
                </View>
            </View >
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f4',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    searchBar: {
        flex: 1,
        top: '5%',
        width: '90%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(242, 242, 244,0.5)'
    },
    merchantsList: {
        flex: 6,
        width: '95%',
    },
    footerBtn: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
    },
    listItem: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 5,
    },

    SelectedlistItem: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 5,
        backgroundColor:"grey",
    },

    btnSelect: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '95%',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderColor: '#00CED1',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 2,
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginLeft: 8,
    },

    btnDsb: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '95%',
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 5,
        marginLeft: 8,
    },
    txtBtn: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#00CED1',
        fontSize: 20,
    },
})
```

above is code that's you want and the screenshot is here
[image]

Comment: Thank you!, It really solve the problem and was exactly what I was looking!

Comment: Beautiful working example. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Since you keep track of the selected `itemId`, you can simply override the style of selected item as below.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.PressedItem(item.id, item.image)} >
    {/* Suppeose you want to change the background color of selected item as 'red' */}
    <View style={item.id !== this.state.itemId ? styles.listItem : [styles.listItem, { backgroundColor: 'red' }]}>
        ...
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But you need to add [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#extradata) property in FlatList for telling the list to re-render.

```
extraData={this.state.itemId}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.